# Is there any way to use Navmesh with physics in unity using steeringTarget and CalculatePath()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

I am trying to make an enemy for my game, and I got it to work using Navmesh. The only problem I have is that my character controller for my player is rigidbody based, and I want the player to be able to push the Navmesh agent around. I think this can be achieved by `CalculatePath()` and `steeringTarget`, but I am still not sure how the code would work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.